# Embed/iframe content as part of parent window

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar, blogs

In creating a page with blog-style content in the middle section, it would be good to use embed/iframe to load content from a separate (html) document into this section. Such a solution would make it more straightforward to update the blog. However, the question is if it's possible to do this without PHP and MySQL (both of which are beyond the scope of this coder).

The code as it stands goes something like this:

```
<section id="bio">
<p>Name</p>
<ul><li>Some data</li></ul>
</section>
<section id="blog">
<iframe src="blog.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;"></iframe>
</section>
<section id="links">
<ul><li>Links listed here</li></ul>
</section>
```

Now, with a blog of some length scrollbars pop up around the blog section. Would it be somehow possible for the iframe content to be considered an intergral part of the page so that the entire content of the iframed file appears prior to the last section, and so that the scrollbars include the entire page content (rather than only the iframe content)?

Answer (score 0):

Iframes can't do that by definition.
However, there are some libraries to help you resize the iframe according to it's content.
Check this: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

You'll need to place a script inside your blog.html and other one in your host page HTML.